# How do I unlock Sniper's "The Last Wave" TF2 achievement?

Tags: achievements, team-fortress-2, tf2-sniper

I'm currently attempting to achieve TF2 achievements, and I can't seem to obtain "The Last Wave":

> **The Last Wave**
>   Provide an enemy with a freezecam shot of you waving to them.

I am under the impression that you just have to taunt with your primary as Sniper after getting a kill, but after doing this many times with lots of different delays between the kill and the taunt I still haven't unlocked the achievement. I have achieved other achievements since I started trying for that one.

The only modifications I've made are a tf2mate config and frankenhud

Comment: You're doing this on servers against players, right? Not against bots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appears to be a bug by which you only obtain this achievement when you obtain the "Be Polite" achievement: once you've provided a freeze cam of each your melee taunt and your primary taunt you get both. Odd.

Comment: Me too. I got both achievements together!